# How do C# Linq extension methods perform equality comparison?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, iequatable

So, the following lambda expression is not returning any elements in the collection, even though while stepping through I was able to verify that 1 item matches the criteria. I've added a sample of the class with it's IEquatable implementation.

```
...within a method, foo is a method parameter
var singleFoo = _barCollection.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Foo == foo);
```

The above returns nothing. Any suggestions as to what to do to make the expression above work?

```
public class Foo: IEquatable<Foo> 
{
    public string KeyProperty {get;set;}
    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return other.KeyProperty==KeyProperty;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (Foo)) return false;
        return Equals((Foo) obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (KeyProperty != null ? KeyProperty.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

To make sure I didn't go insane, I created the following nUnit test which passes:

```
    [Test]
    public void verify_foo_comparison_works()
    {
        var keyString = "keyValue";
        var bar = new Bar();
        bar.Foo = new Foo { KeyProperty = keyString };
        var basicFoo = new Foo { KeyProperty = keyString };
        var fromCollectionFoo = Bars.SingleFooWithKeyValue;
        Assert.AreEqual(bar.Foo,basicFoo);
        Assert.AreEqual(bar.Foo, fromCollectionFoo);
        Assert.AreEqual(basicFoo, fromCollectionFoo);
    }
```

Attempt at overriding == and !=:

```
    public static bool operator ==(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if ((object)x == null || (object)y == null)
            return false;
        return x.KeyProperty == y.KeyProperty;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting KeyProperty properly on all instances?  You do this explicitly in your nUnit tests...

Comment: Yes. While stepping through I have verified that the KeyProperty value is set.

Answer (score 5):

They use [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) for equality comparisons and [`Comparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx) for ordered comparisons.

> #### MSDN - `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` Remarks:
>
> The `Default` property checks whether type `T` implements the `System.IEquatable(Of T)` generic interface and if so returns an `EqualityComparer(Of T)` that uses that implementation. Otherwise it returns an `EqualityComparer(Of T)` that uses the overrides of `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` provided by `T`.
>
> #### MSDN - `Comparer<T>.Default` Remarks:
>
> The `Comparer(Of T)` returned by this property uses the `System.IComparable(Of T)` generic interface (`IComparable<T>` in C#, `IComparable(Of T)` in Visual Basic) to compare two objects. If type `T` does not implement the `System.IComparable(Of T)` generic interface, this property returns a `Comparer(Of T)` that uses the `System.IComparable` interface.

Answer (score 4):

You are not redefining the == operator.

Change to:

```
var singleFoo = _barCollection.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Foo.Equals(foo));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I'd rather not refactor all the places where the "bar.Foo == foo" has been implemented.

Comment: No problem. Define == on Foo and you can keep the predicates as is.

Comment: Overwrote == and != as below and still no such luck. 

I gave up and refactored to use your initial suggestion. (I updated the original post to show the == and != implementations.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also [override the == operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I'd rather switch to using the`Equals` method, like @Timores does.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit a similar problem with an IdentityKey class (that has implicit Guid conversions) - in this instance it's not really feasible to include an `== operator` override.

I say it's not feasible because with "mixed" comparisons I'll now have to cast the types to avoid ambiguity for the == operator overloads.
**ie.** Instead of `if(guidValue = identityKeyValue)` it has to become `if((IdentityKey)guidValue == identityKeyValue)`

Whilst using `.Equals` is a solution, it doesn't feel natural to me?

Comment: If this is intended to be a question, please post it as a *question* and not as an *answer*.  If it in some way depends on this question, link it in your own question and explain why it does not solve your problem.